# Checking for local extrema of two variable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=xye^{-(x+y)}$.

I want to check for local extrema and saddle points.

The gradient is given by:

$\nabla f(x,y)=((y-xy)e^{-(x+y)}, (x-xy)e^{-(x+y)})$

Solving this for $0$ gives the two candidates $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$

The Hessian is given by:

$\operatorname{Hess}f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-(x+y)}(xy-2y)& e^{-(x+y)}(xy+1-x-y)\\e^{-(x+y)}(xy+1-x-y)&e^{-(x+y)}(xy-2x)\end{pmatrix}$

Now I investigate

$\operatorname{Hess}f(0,0)=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$

$\operatorname{Hess}f(1,1)=\begin{pmatrix} -e^{-2}&0\\0&-e^{-2}\end{pmatrix}$

and see that both matrices are indefinite. For example with the Hurwitz criterion for the determinant of the minors.

Is this correct?
In particular, can you spot saddle points with the Hurwitz criterion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use the Second Derivatives Test?

Comment: What is the second derivative test? I do not recognize the "name".

Comment: second partials Test at: https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Montana_State_University/M273%3A_Multivariable_Calculus/14%3A_Functions_of_Multiple_Variables_and_Partial_Derivatives/Optimization_of_Functions_of_Several_Variables. Also, you show $f(-1,-1)$, but I think you meant $f(1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. I will take a look at the link.

Comment: @moo As it seems to me the "Second Derivatives Test" is the same as the "Hurwitz criterion". You would check the determinant of the minors.

Comment: Yes, but the list of choices there provides a saddle and a local max for your problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Moo No, you are right. Thanks, I did not read it all the way through. I think this answers my question.